# jQuery give NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR errors in Firefox

Tags: jquery

so, guys, I know I am way over my head, so have pity. I'm trying to learn.

This is in file called ifx.js

I had programmers work on my project, and it's been fine, until recently on Firefox, where it just.... isnt.

The Error received when I try to perform the action (opening a horizontal menu) is:

```
Error: [Exception... "Security error" code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)" location: "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/~yvonechr/users/lib/ifx.js Line: 389"]
```

The area in the file is here: (line ending in NULL is line 389 [CODE]

```
for (p in prop) {
    if (p == 'style') {
        var newStyles = jQuery.parseStyle(prop[p]);
        for (np in newStyles) {
            this.getValues(np, newStyles[np]);
        }
    } else if (p == 'className') {
        if (document.styleSheets) for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            var cssRules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules || document.styleSheets[i].rules || null;
            if (cssRules) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cssRules.length; j++) {
                    if (cssRules[j].selectorText == '.' + prop[p]) {
                        var rule = new RegExp('\.' + prop[p] + ' {');
                        var styles = cssRules[j].style.cssText;
                        var newStyles = jQuery.parseStyle(styles.replace(rule, '').replace(/}/g, ''));
                        for (np in newStyles) {
                            this.getValues(np, newStyles[np]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.getValues(p, prop[p]);
```

I'm sorry if this post is just so wrong, but I'll learn, really. And if anyone can help me, I'll be so thankful, you won't believe it.

Comment: Read http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=cs&comments_parentId=377420&forumId=1. Is the JS coming from a different domain?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably because your css file is hosted in another domain and you're trying to access cssRules.

If it is possible you should host your css file in the same domain and it will work.

I found this [blog post](http://mrclay.org/index.php/2008/09/06/case-of-the-ns_error_dom_security_err/) describing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to debug this, just figured out this error is also thrown if you attempt to set the `.val()` on a file field. I was doing it on accident and it took a while to identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Error: [Exception... "Security error" code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"

Answer : The problem is probably because you wrote prototype.js more than one (in php form).